# Power BI Date Parsing

Tags: microsoft-powerbi

I'm loading a CSV datafile into Power BI web version that includes a date field in the format and data like this:

2013-08-07 16:32:35,Test,Test

This results in Power BI creating some additional columns for Month, Year, and day that greatly help in summarizing the data.

[image: What I Want]

When I load the same CSV file into Power BI Desktop, it does NOT create the additional columns of helpful data.

Is there a way to tell Power BI Desktop to do this, or create the same manually? Am I missing some critical piece of date formatting documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW I don't get the same behaviour loading a CSV file into the Power BI Web service - I only see the original columns in text form.

Anyway you can add those columns manually in Power BI Desktop, using the **Edit Queries** window.  Within that window, select your source column (e.g. "closed"), then go to the **Add Column** ribbon and choose from the menu under the **Date** button.  For example clicking **Date / Year / Year** will add a "Year" column with the year portion of the "closed" date.

You will need to rename columns manually to match your example above. When you are done, go back to the **Home** ribbon and click **Close & Apply** to update your model.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Mike! This basically replicates the exact behavior that somehow I was getting PowerBI to do for me automatically. Still a mystery why it only sometimes is automatic, but this seems to be the solution. Thanks!